# Adding / Removing addresses to connections via network manager cli (nmcli)

Tags: networking, networkmanager, nmcli

I am going through some official Linux Foundation exercises / documentation.

In a lecture about adding / removing an ip address to an existing connection, the following example is cited:

```
sudo nmcli con modify "Auto Ethernet" -ipv4.addresses 172.16.2.140/24
```

Why is the above CIDR used given that it corresponds to 256 IP addresses?

Shouldn't we be using the `/32` suffix for **unique** IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `/24` suffix is used to specify the broadcast domain (your broadcast will reach all of the 256-2 addresses in the subnet), using `/32` subnet mask you will not able to connect to anything in your local network (not even your gateway).